# RecyclerView snapshot

Tags: java, android

I am having problem in snapshot of recyclerview.
How do i take snapshot of the few elements of recyclerview. like from 1 to 20, then 20 to 40 and so on.
kindly help me

i tried alot i can't take pictures dynamically of the recyclerview

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //datamodel.setName(etname.getText().toString());
    //datamodel.setAge((Integer.parseInt(etage.getText().toString())));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
    {
        DataModel datamodel = new DataModel("umair", i);
        data.add(datamodel);
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void slice()
{
    slice = new ArrayList<>();
    int strtnum = Integer.parseInt(start.getText().toString());
    int endnum = Integer.parseInt(end.getText().toString());

    for (int i = strtnum; i < endnum; i++)
    {
        Log.d("test", "" + start + "" + end);

        DataModel item = (DataModel)data.get(i);
        DataModel item2 = new DataModel(item.getName(), item.getAge());
        slice.add(item2);

        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(slice);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "start" + start + "end" + end, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```